# Transform a JSON array of objects with MySQL 5.7 (map)

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-json

I'm stuck with MySQL 5.7 and to reduce the amount of data retrieved I need to transform a JSON array within a SQL query.

My column is JSON and with a value structured like that:

```json
{
  "foo": [{
    "bar" : "BAR1",
    "baz" : "BAZ1",
    "qux" : "QUX1"
  }, {
    "bar" : "BAR2",
    "baz" : "BAZ2",
    "qux" : "QUX2"
  }]
}
```

I don't know how many items are in the array.
I want the result to be structured like that:

```json
{
  "foo" : [
    ["BAR1", "BAZ1"],
    ["BAR2", "BAZ2"]
  ]
}
```

Basically I need to transform item objects to arrays (and skip `qux`).

Unfortunately [`JSON_REMOVE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-remove) does not allow wildcard:

> An error occurs if [...] any path argument is not a valid path expression or contains a * or ** wildcard.

Is it possible to pass [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) results as [`JSON_ARRAY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-array) or [`JSON_REMOVE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-remove) arguments?

Comment: Do you have to do it in MySQL? A script in Python or PHP could do this more easily.

Comment: This will be pretty difficult in 5.7. In 8.0 you could use `JSON_TABLE()` and `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` to transform it. If you can't do that, you'll need to write a stored procedure with a loop.

Comment: I need to filter out data before getting it from DB (I have AWS Aurora Serverless restrictions about maximum amount if retrieved data ‍♂️)

Comment: Then it will have to be a loop in a stored procedure.